# How to backup XAMPP content? I need to run it on another laptop soon

Tags: wordpress, joomla, xampp, backup

I have one Joomla site and one WordPress site in it. My laptop hard drive is failing. I have zipped my htdocs folder but that's about it

*** excellent answers, just exported my database right before a crash. ***

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your simple expression, I could only answer below.

If you want to run the exactly the same website in another computer. you will need to backup all the related items including the database and plugins installed and then restore them in your new computer.

Answer (score 1):

**Backup of project**

- You can download entire project from `htdocs` folder or `htdocs` folder itself.
- In this way you will get all your previous project.

**Backup Database backup.**

- Now you go to you phpmyadmin from url and export all DB.
  you can do it by login to http://localhost/phpmyadmin => export

Now Just replace htdocs folder with your new laptop htdocs folder or put project file there in new htdocs folder.
and import DB backup to your xamp phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

htdocs is good for all your files, but you still need to backup your databases. Use the database export function in phpMyAdmin (https://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database), then you will need to import those databases when you have xampp setup on the new computer.